What is the best way to answer the phone in English
I just received a call from California and when the lady said "I am looking for Quique" I immediately replied it's him, I think I should have said something along the lines of "This is him" or "speaking" I was going to say "That's me" but I thought it to be rude or inadequate a very informal way to answer to a stranger.
What would be the most polite way to answer the phone in the U.S. and the UK? I get calls from both places

All your answers are good. Then you might add How can I help you? to your answer: "Yes, this is Quique. Can I help you?"

If I am the sought-after person I generally just answer "Speaking" (west coast AME if it matters).

"Quique speaking. How can I help you?" is polite enough. But I wonder if they could pronounce your name correctly. If not you can correct them.

Once you say your name, you have modeled how you pronounce it and won't need to correct an incorrect way.

Other than "Speaking", the standard formal confirmation that you are the sought person on the phone is "This is he" or she, not him, her.

@FumbleFingers - 'standard' in 1934 maybe? Father, it is I who broke the window. Well done, my boy, for confessing, but I must still beat you.

@MichaelHarvey: Well, in my experience, practically everyone says "Speaking" in this context anyway. But imho if you're gonna be ultra-formal, it's he, not him.

This is he=the most formal way to say it. OR This is Quiqui. And you have not answered my question re  your interpreting issue.

The specific phrase is "Quique speaking" or just "speaking".
But I wouldn't find any of your suggestions to be particularly rude or impolite. In particular "That's me." seems fine, and friendly/informal rather than impolite.
As noted, it would be normal to continue by asking "how can I help?" or "who is calling?" or some other question to move the conversation forward.
